# Do I need to keep my high school transcripts?

Tags: transcript-of-records

I graduated high school in the United States and I have a bachelors degree from an accredited university in the United States as well.  Would I need to keep my high school transcripts for any purpose?  For example, Grad school in the US or abroad or any other need?

Comment: I don't think anyone will ask for them but why would you NOT keep them?

Comment: @earthling Trying to get rid of excess clutter and debating whether to scan them and then throw them a away.

Answer (score 2):

Grad school applications typically only want your undergraduate transcript since that is your highest level of education (and most recent). This is the system in Canada, and I can't think of a reason it would be different in the US.

Comment: It is no different in the US.

Comment: I vividly remember academic job applications that wanted my undergrad grades, and I vaguely remember a grad school that was interested in my high school grades. It's been a few years though, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Just for the entertainment value: I know of at least one German university that requested every transcript, including high school, for applications for a position as a (full) professor. It was some years ago and I think it was an administration thing and no one really cared in the end.